# Photon propagator inverse

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, tensor-calculus

If i have the operator $D^{\mu\nu}=\partial^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}+m\epsilon^{\mu\alpha\nu}\partial_{\alpha}$. What's your inverse $(D^{\mu\nu})^{-1}$?

Answer (score -1):

$$
\frac{\eta^{\mu\nu}}{\Box}
$$

Comment: how did you get this answer?

Comment: using Fourier transform on $D^{\mu\nu}$, then $\eta^{\mu\nu}/k^2$ is clearly the inverse.

Comment: This is the answer for $m=0$. The term proportional to $m$ comes from a Chern-Simons term and should make the photon massive.

Comment: He asked about the inverse of the operator, which makes my answer mathematically correct for any $m$ simply because $D^{-1}D=1$... Now if he specifies a lagrangian which turns out to be invariant under a gauge transformation, then one has to introduce a gauge fixing term first (e.g. $1/\xi (\partial\cdot A)^2$) and then invert. Only then it would become clear that there is a single transverse massive excitation in $(1+2)$ dimensions.

Comment: In other words, the operator for whose inverse he should have asked, should have been $\eta^{\mu\nu}\Box-\partial^\mu\partial^\nu + m \epsilon^{\mu\nu\sigma}\partial_\sigma$, for topologically massive abelian chern-simons theory.

Comment: I'm sure it took you a long time to whip up that latex, but it is of no surprise to me that this was sent to the low quality review for potential deletion. Please consider updating your answer to include relevant details (e.g., how you got the answer, why it suffices, what it means), rather than keeping the entirely useless and uninformative form that it currently is in.

Comment: I guess that to introduce a gauge fixing $\frac{1}{\lambda}(\partial\cdot A)^{2}$, the operator have that be singular, in this case is not.

Comment: Then there is no gauge invariance, & this is not QED with chern simons as @MengCheng suggested, which validated the original answer